# Convert Apache Spark Scala code to Python

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

Can anyone convert this very simple scala code to python?

```
val words = Array("one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three")
val wordPairsRDD = sc.parallelize(words).map(word => (word, 1))

val wordCountsWithGroup = wordPairsRDD
    .groupByKey()
    .map(t => (t._1, t._2.sum))
    .collect()
```

Comment: What do you expect the output of the code to be? I would guess that code is counting word occurrences, right? So is the expected output { "one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three" : 3} ?

Comment: `import collections;words = ["one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three"];collections.Counter(words)` would work if `{ "one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three" : 3} ` is what you want.

Comment: yes i'm expecting output like this : [('one', 1), ('two', 3), ('three', 3)]. what will be the python code for .map(t => (t._1, t._2.sum)) line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
words = ["one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three"]
wordPairsRDD = sc.parallelize(words).map(lambda word : (word, 1))

wordCountsWithGroup = wordPairsRDD
    .groupByKey()
    .map(lambda t: (t[0], sum(t[1])))
    .collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

Two translate in python :

```
from operator import add
wordsList = ["one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three"]
words = sc.parallelize(wordsList ).map(lambda l :(l,1)).reduceByKey(add).collect()
print words
words = sc.parallelize(wordsList ).map(lambda l : (l,1)).groupByKey().map(lambda t: (t[0], sum(t[1]))).collect()
print words
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have a Spark context defined and ready to go:

```
 from operator import add
 words = ["one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three"]
 wordsPairRDD = sc.parallelize(words).map(lambda word: (word, 1))
      .reduceByKey(add)
      .collect()
```

Checkout the github examples repo: [Python Examples](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/python)